# Couchdb server error (500 system_limit)

Tags: python, couchdb, ubuntu-12.04

My program is written in python. I use couchdb-python for data storage. But when the program stores datas, it gives an error.:

```
File "/home/koc/dnsReputation/dnsDatabase.py", line 45, in checkHashValue
  if len(result) == 0:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 987, in __len__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 1003, in rows
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 990, in _fetch
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/client.py", line 914, in _exec
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 399, in post_json
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 381, in post
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 419, in _request
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/CouchDB-0.8-py2.6.egg/couchdb/http.py", line 310, in request
couchdb.http.ServerError: (500, ('error', 'system_limit'))
```

I didn't understand why. any answer is appriciated. Thanks

Edited 13.07:

In couch.log, these lines are written:

```
{error_report,<0.32.0>,
                    {<0.125.0>,crash_report,
                     [[{initial_call,
                           {mochiweb_socket_server,init,['Argument__1']}},
                       {pid,<0.125.0>},
                       {registered_name,[]},
                       {error_info,
                           {exit,eaddrinuse,
                               [{gen_server,init_it,6},
                                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}},
                       {ancestors,
                           [couch_secondary_services,couch_server_sup,
                            <0.33.0>]},
                       {messages,[]},
                       {links,[<0.95.0>]},
                       {dictionary,[]},
                       {trap_exit,true},
                       {status,running},
                       {heap_size,987},
                       {stack_size,24},
                       {reductions,460}],
                      []]}}
```

Comment: This looks relevant: http://osdir.com/ml/CouchDB-Python/2011-05/msg00030.html

Answer (score 1):

Check your couchdb log for further info - sounds like you have hit an internal Erlang limit as documented on this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/couchdb/+bug/459241).

> Erlang has a default limit of 1024 ports, where each FD, tcp
>   connection, and linked-in driver uses one port. You seem to have
>   exceeded this. You can change it at runtime using the ERL_MAX_PORTS
>   env variable.

**Update after additional log info:** The `eaddrinuse` from your log makes it look like you have some port conflict or lack of permission for the view server to be running on a port you've configured. Check your couchdb port configuration and check if anything else on your system is running on those ports already.

Comment: I check the ports which is being used by couchdb. there is only one. And even though I run the program again, it immediately fails when first query is done.

Comment: Any clues from the couchdb log?

Comment: Last line is : "[Thu, 12 Jul 2012 00:21:16 GMT] [info] [<0.8909.6>] 127.0.0.1 - - 'POST' /dnsrecords/_temp_view 500"..
When temp view is done, it gives an error.

Comment: I can't help you with just "an error". Add the actual couchdb log error to your original question. The result from your python program is just an after-effect. You should see something in the couchdb.log that looks like: `{"error":"case_clause","reason":"{system_limit, ...`

Comment: Error info in couch.log has been added on the question